# How to Create a new Admin User for A WordPress Site via MySQL (PHPMyAdmin)?

Tags: wordpress

My WordPress site got hacked and the WP Admin user account password was changed by the hacker. This essentially locked the user out of his admin dashboard. It is best (for situations like this) to just create a new admin user account to gain access to WP admin dashboard and fix things as needed.

Is it possible to create a new WordPress admin user account via MySQL database (without having access to your WordPress admin dashboard).

**N.B: I am site owner and I have access to cPanel/Control Panel of my server.**

Comment: what is DB prefix of tables?is is wp_ ?

Comment: By default WordPress DB structure and table prefix `wp_`.

Comment: If you have got the answer that solves your issue, please up vote + mark the answer as the one that solves your issue. ;) :) Thank you

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Run below Query from msql :

```
 INSERT INTO `wp_users` (`user_login`, `user_pass`, `user_nicename`, `user_email`, `user_status`) VALUES ('your username', MD5('your password'), 'your firstname & your lastname', 'your email', '0');
```

take created user id from table after successfully run query insert below queries:

```
INSERT INTO `wp_usermeta` (`umeta_id`, `user_id`, `meta_key`, `meta_value`) VALUES (NULL, (Select max(id) FROM wp_users), 'wp_capabilities', 'a:1:{s:13:"administrator";s:1:"1";}');

INSERT INTO `wp_usermeta` (`umeta_id`, `user_id`, `meta_key`, `meta_value`) VALUES (NULL, (Select max(id) FROM wp_users), 'wp_user_level', '10');
```

Comment: What if this doesnt work ? I found this answer all over the internet, but still doesnt work for me.

Comment: @TomaTomov there could be many reasons, with 1 client I have seen, they have a vendor to their wordpress and there are some composer modules in there (1 of them named roots/wp-password-bcrypt) that change some of how the login works. I found that I needed to remove these packages for my md5 based login to work!

Answer (score 0):

Just checked the wordpress structure.
So, the password is a md5 one. Go to http://www.miraclesalad.com/webtools/md5.php and enter the desired password. You will need it.

**If you have access to phpMyAdmin using cPanel**, just go to the table wp_users or something related where users are stored, and locate the username that you want to edit. Just look for the username that matches your admin name. Click edit and paste the previously generated md5 password in the password field. Save it and you should be ready to go :)

**Otherwise, using a SQL command it'd be like**:

1. Retrieve the user ID that you want to change:

   SELECT ID, user_login, user_pass FROM wp_users;
2. Change it's password:

   UPDATE wp_users SET user_pass="****" WHERE ID = ****;

Replace the '****' for the password that you generated in the site, and the id for the ID that you retrieved in 1.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, even if the password has been changed you should be able to reset your password using the default "Forgot My Password" process of the WordPress.

If the hacker changed your e-mail address too, then you have also to update your e-mail address.

In any way the solution is to open the `PREFIX_users` table ( where `PREFIX_` usually is `wp_` bat can be anything else ), and update the current password with a new MD5 hash of your password. Also check the column `user_email` if it contains the correct e-mail address.

If you like to execute a single SQL query run this:

```
UPDATE wp_users SET user_pass='MD5HASH', user_email='your-email-address' WHERE user_login = 'your_user_name'
```

The `MD5HASH` is the string you get when you enter here ( http://www.miraclesalad.com/webtools/md5.php ) in the text area. The MD5 hash looks like this :`e10adc3949ba59abbe56e057f20f883e`

The `your-email-address` should be equal to your e-mail address

The `your_user_name` should be equal to the user name you use to login the WordPress.

Finaly note, if you have prefix other than `wp_` then update the `wp_users` with your prefix + `users`

By following this method, the next time you will login the WordPress Dashboard, the WordPress will replace the MD5 HASH with a new HASH that even more secure.

If you are looking to create a new user it is more complicated, because you should register also meta options with all the rules, etc.

Start by trying to replace the password and the e-mail and I think you will gain again your access.

Answer (score 0):

This tool lets you generate the SQL code automatically via a user interface to create a new Wordpress admin user, just modify the database name, user and  and password you want, and copy/paste the code into phpMyAdmin: http://cssshowcase.co.uk/wordpress-sql-create-new-admin-user-phpmyadmin/

That's what I'm using everytime I don't know the client's admin password, and I don't want to reset their password directly. I hope it helps ;)