# How to Recreate users table in WordPress?

Tags: wordpress

I am unable to log in to my WordPress website. The website is working fine, and user credentials are correct.

Later I found that somehow the `users` table got corrupted and now it got deleted.

Can you explain how I can create `users` tables with an admin user login credentials so that I can log in back to my WordPress?

I have access to phpMyAdmin.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your table name is `wp_users` adjust for your prefix.

From: `wp-admin\includes\schema.php Line 191`

```
CREATE TABLE `wp_users` (
  ID bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
  user_login varchar(60) NOT NULL default '',
  user_pass varchar(255) NOT NULL default '',
  user_nicename varchar(50) NOT NULL default '',
  user_email varchar(100) NOT NULL default '',
  user_url varchar(100) NOT NULL default '',
  user_registered datetime NOT NULL default '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  user_activation_key varchar(255) NOT NULL default '',
  user_status int(11) NOT NULL default '0',
  display_name varchar(250) NOT NULL default '',
  PRIMARY KEY  (ID),
  KEY user_login_key (user_login),
  KEY user_nicename (user_nicename),
  KEY user_email (user_email)
)
```

You can also add the Primary Keys and `AUTO_INCREMENT` via the phpMyAdmin Interface like so:

[image: phpMyAdmin Screen Shot]

Then follow these instructions:

[How to Create a new Admin User for A WordPress Site via MySQL (PHPMyAdmin)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42255378/how-to-create-a-new-admin-user-for-a-wordpress-site-via-mysql-phpmyadmin)

Comment: Hello Howard,

Your solution creates ```wp_users``` table.

But like Gaurav's solution, this table is not gets listed in the left bar of the phpMyAdmin.

I can see ```wp_users``` on the right side https://i.imgur.com/Ze2Vayv.png

In the search bar, ```wp_users``` doesn't show in result https://i.imgur.com/7L3yDRl.png

But when I created the ```wp_users``` left side pagination appears. So if I select 2 from that list, I see https://i.imgur.com/X3MkyCd.png

If I click on the ```wp_users``` table, I see users but https://i.imgur.com/WQbeVhJ.png

I see no Edit, Delete options.

Comment: I added a screenshot from phpMyAdmin so you can see what needs to be adjusted in the structure to make your existing table work.  But then you'd have to number all of the ID's.  So it may just be easier to drop table wp_users and start over.  Also delete any wp_usermeta

Answer (score 0):

You can make a small PHP file, let's call it `make_user.php`, containing the following code:

```
<?php
define('ADMIN_USER', 'my_admin_user');
define('ADMIN_MAIL', 'my_admin@mail.com');
require_once('./wp-load.php');

if (! get_user_by('email', ADMIN_MAIL)) {
  $passwd = wp_generate_password(20);
  $user_id = wp_create_user(ADMIN_USER, $passwd, ADMIN_MAIL);
  $user = get_user_by('id', $user_id);
  $user->set_role('administrator');
  echo "User created.".PHP_EOL;
  //echo "Password is: $passwd";
} else {
  echo "User already exists.";
}
```

Change your ADMIN_USER (account name) and ADMIN_MAIL to whatever you want.

Upload this to the root folder of your WP installation and call it by http://your.host/make_user.php .
You can either decide to uncomment the line echoing the password and use this, or just reset it via the regular Forgot password function (I'd do the latter).

Delete the file after you're done.

Comment: I tried your solution initially, but it was throwing wp_user table did not exist.

So, I used other's solution and tried to run yours again and here is the error I get.

Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function set_role() on bool in /home/example.com/public_html/make_user.php:10 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in /home/example.com/public_html/make_user.php on line 10
There has been a critical error on your website.

Answer (score 0):

Step 1: Create user_reg.php file in  wp root folder and file containing the following code

```
/*
* Code start
*/ 

//Create wp_users table

include 'wp-load.php';

global $table_prefix, $wpdb;

$tblname = 'users';
$wp_track_table = $table_prefix . "$tblname ";
if($wpdb->get_var( "show tables like '$wp_track_table'" ) != $wp_track_table) {

    $sql = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS {$wp_track_table} (
      `ID` bigint(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
      `user_login` varchar(60) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
      `user_pass` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
      `user_nicename` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
      `user_email` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
      `user_url` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
      `user_registered` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
      `user_activation_key` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
      `user_status` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
      `display_name` varchar(250) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT ''
    ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci;";

    require_once( ABSPATH . '/wp-admin/includes/upgrade.php' );
    dbDelta($sql);
}


//Create user 

//start: Fill you details here 
$user_login = 'lores'; 
$user_email = 'lores@gmail.com';
$user_pass = 'lores@123';
$display_name = 'mark lores';
$first_name = 'mark';
$last_name = 'lores';
//end: Fill you details here 


$flag_1 = 0;
$flag_2 = 0;

$check_username_exists = username_exists( $user_login );
if ($check_username_exists) {
    $flag_1 = 1;
}

$check_email_exists = email_exists($user_email);
if ($check_email_exists) {
    $flag_2 = 1;
}


if ($flag_1 == 0 && $flag_2 == 0) { 

     $userdata = array(
                'user_login'  =>  $user_login,
                'user_pass'   =>  $user_pass,
                'user_email'  =>  $user_email,
                'display_name'=>  $display_name,
                'first_name'  =>  $first_name,
                'last_name'   =>  $last_name
            );

    $user_id = wp_insert_user($userdata);

    wp_update_user( array ('ID' => $user_id, 'role' => 'administrator') );

    if(is_wp_error($user_id)){

        echo $user->get_error_message();

    }else{

        echo "User created successfully";
    }


}else{

    echo "User already exist";
}


/*
* Code end
*/
```

Step 2: Run the file on browser like 
http://example.com/user_reg.php

Step 3: If user-created successfully then try to login with given username  and password

Comment: Hello Gaurav,

Your solution creates ```wp_users``` table, and I can see the user registration successful.

But this table is not gets listed in the left bar of the phpMyAdmin.

I can see ```wp_users``` on the right side https://i.imgur.com/Ze2Vayv.png

In the search bar, ```wp_users``` doesn't show in result https://i.imgur.com/7L3yDRl.png

But when I created the ```wp_users``` left side pagination appears. So if I select 2 from that list, I see https://i.imgur.com/X3MkyCd.png

If I click on the ```wp_users``` table, I see users but https://i.imgur.com/WQbeVhJ.png

Comment: Here I can see in your screenshots the wp_users table is already created and corrupted. Please rename or delete the wp_usres table from the database but before that, you have to take a table backup and follow Step 2 again.

Comment: Hello Gaurav,

Interestingly, I created this ```wp_users``` today.

Every time I do this, the same error happens.

Comment: If you have created wp_usres today so could you please check table corrupted or not and let me know first

If the table is corrupted so you can't perform the edit delete operation on wp_usres table

and why auto-incremented ID is 0  in wp_usres table
https://prnt.sc/rc2f1s

Comment: Note: auto-incremented ID should like this 
https://prnt.sc/rc2hkt